# How do I determine the number of rows and columns in a gnome-terminal window while resizing?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm running Fedora 21 which comes with gnome 3.14. In older versions, when I resized a terminal, a little box would appear that showed the dimensions of the terminal (in columns and rows, not pixels; defaulting to 24x80). Now when I resize the terminal, this box doesn't appear. How do I re-enable this feature, or otherwise determine the number of rows and columns in my terminal?

Comment: IIRC they removed the tooltip and then re-added it... works fine with gnome-terminal 3.14.2 but only when using the mouse to resize the window.

Comment: @don_crissti, that's a shame. I've removed window decorations from my terminals and rely on a keyboard shortcut to resize them; I can't resize them with a mouse.

Comment: FWIW, it's fixed in 3.16 (works with both keyboard and mouse).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [some quick searching](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1178429), it doesn't look like there is a way to get gnome to display the dimensions.

You can run these commands inside the terminal window to get the lines and columns respectively:

```
tput lines
tput cols
```